# Batch file running a command in every subfolder

Tags: batch-file

Basic question - Is it possible to create a batch file that will run from a folder and run a command in every subfolder?

More details - I have school whose teachers are fulling the server with thousands of 10+ megapixel images.  I'd like to tell them to save to a set location then have a scheduled task run a batch file that will run a IrfanView command line in that folder and all subfolders to resize the images (IrfanView won't do it itself).
I can figure out the IrfanView command line I need but beyond that I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

see `HELP FOR` and then try this in the command line `FOR /D %d IN (*.*) DO @ECHO %d`

Comment: Thanks for the response @PA.  Sorry but I'm a real scripting novice and trying to wrap my head around this is giving me the brain hurt.

If the all the folders I need to run the command in are in c:\test and the command itself is

"%programfiles%\irfanview\i_view32.exe" *.jpg /resize_long=1632 /resample /aspectratio /convert=*.jpg

How do I alter your answer to include these?

I'm sorry for my denseness and I really am trying to understand how the command works.
Again any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try the command line I suggested, and begin adding, step by step, your program invocation in the ECHO command... you will enjoy your own progress towards the solution.